Nginx custom 404 page not displaying when URL meets certain conditions
I'm trying to configure Nginx to serve a custom 404 error page when the URL contains multiple slashes (e.g., http://yourdomain.com//page). However, the custom 404 page isn't being displayed as expected. Instead, it returns a default Nginx 404 error.
Here's my current Nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "//") {
        return 404;
    }
}

Problem:
When I visit a URL with multiple slashes, such as http://yourdomain.com//test, Nginx correctly returns a 404 status code, but it doesn't show the custom 404.html page. Instead, I see the default Nginx 404 error page.
What I've tried:

Ensuring that proxy_intercept_errors is turned on.
Checking that the 404.html page exists in the root directory.
Removing the if block for testing, which does display the custom 404 page for other non-existent URLs.

What am I missing?
Why isn't the custom 404 page being displayed when using the if block to catch URLs with multiple slashes? Is there a different way to handle this scenario?
Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!
